# Layout Change causing crash

Tags: android

I'm trying to modify my layout but whenever i use the graphical layout it ends up breaking and giving a error seen below. I know this is not the issue since it works when i undo my changes. It's only when i use the graphical layout. If i use the XML it works just fine. I know it says it's in my java code but switching the xml layout shouldn't cause this error. Line 294 is `mEnergy = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnEnergy);`

```
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ToggleButton cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.ChartingFragment.onCreateView(ChartingFragment.java:294)
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
07-08 09:39:22.527: E/AndroidRuntime(22345):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Now here's one that doesn't work once i use the graphical layout to move things around:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/charting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="550dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/charting_header"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/pickdate"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dateselected"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/date"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="#00000000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dateselected"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pickdate"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stamp"
            android:layout_width="192dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="@string/stamp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pickdate"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Methods"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/stamp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="@string/temp"
            android:paddingTop="10sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnstamp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:contentDescription="@string/stampval"
            android:src="@drawable/observation" 
            android:background="#00000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/EditText03"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Body"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkFertile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tempvalue"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tempvalue" 
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fertile"/>

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/btnIntercorse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnMood"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/Intercourse" 
            android:background="@drawable/intercorse_button"
            android:paddingTop="25sp"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/btnHeadache"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnMood"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/measurecervix"
            android:text="@string/headache" 
            android:background="@drawable/headache_button"
            android:paddingTop="25sp"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnEnergy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnMood"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/energy"
            android:text="@string/energy"
            android:paddingTop="25sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:padding="7sp"
            android:paddingTop="25sp"
            android:src="@drawable/mood"
            android:text="@string/mood" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPeriod"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnEnergy"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnIntercorse"
            android:background="@drawable/period_button"
            android:text="@string/period"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/btnTest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnPeriod"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnPeriod"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/measurecervix"
            android:background="@drawable/pregnancy_button"
            android:text="@string/pregnancytest"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""
            android:paddingRight="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnPeriod"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnPeriod"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnPeriod"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/period"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnEnergy"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnEnergy"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/energy"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnIntercorse"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnIntercorse"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/Intercourse"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnHeadache"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/headache"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/pregnancytest"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fertile"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/temp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="@string/fertile"
            android:paddingTop="10sp" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/EditText03"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fertile"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="@string/cervix"
            android:paddingTop="10sp" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/measurecervix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/EditText03"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/EditText03"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tempvalue"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/tempval"
            android:inputType="number" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tempvalue"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/temp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/temp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnstamp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/tempval"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/mood"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Notes Field -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/chartingnote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:background="#C4C6CF"
        android:ems="20"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/hintNote"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <!-- Update Button -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chartingupdate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/charting_update" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Java:

```
public class ChartingFragment extends Fragment implements OnDateSetListener, OnClickListener {
    SharedPreferences mPreferences;
    Boolean symptothermal, mucus_stamps, fertile_infertile;
    EditText sqlNotes, sqlDate, sqlTemperature, sqlmeasurecervix;
    CheckBox sqlFertile;
    int mood_selected, stamp_selected, energy_selected;
    Button update;
    ToggleButton mIntercorse, mPeriod, mHeadache, mTest;
    ImageButton mMood, stamp, date, mEnergy;
    private static final int ID_HAPPY = 1;
    private static final int ID_SAD = 2;
    private static final int ID_MAD = 3;
    private static final int ID_CRY = 4;
    private static final int ID_ARROUSED = 5;
    private static final int ID_SLEEPY = 6;
    private static final int _ID1 = 1;
    private static final int _ID2 = 2;
    private static final int _ID3 = 3;
    private static final int _ID4 = 4;
    private static final int _ID5 = 5;
    private static final int _ID6 = 6;
    private static final int _ID7 = 7;
    private static final int _ID8 = 8;
    private static final int _ID9 = 9;
    private static final int _ID10 = 10;
    private static final int _ID11 = 11;
    private static final int _ID12 = 12;
    private static final int _ID13 = 13;
    private static final int _ID14 = 14;
    private static final int _ID15 = 15;
    URL SERVICE_URL;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
    }           

    private void init() {
        mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        symptothermal = mPreferences.getBoolean("symptothermal", true);
        mucus_stamps = mPreferences.getBoolean("mucus_stamps", true);
        fertile_infertile = mPreferences.getBoolean("fertile_infertil", true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view;

        view = setcontrolvisability(inflater);

        update = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.chartingupdate);
        update.setOnClickListener(this);

        date = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.pickdate);
        date.setOnClickListener(this);

        date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                   DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerDialogFragment(ChartingFragment.this);
                   newFragment.show(ft, "date_picker_dialog");
               }
        });



        final QuickAction mQuickAction  = new QuickAction(getActivity());

        ActionItem happyItem        = new ActionItem(ID_HAPPY, "Happy", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.emo_happy));
        ActionItem sadtItem         = new ActionItem(ID_SAD, "Sad", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.emo_sad));
        ActionItem madItem          = new ActionItem(ID_MAD, "Mad", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.emo_mad));
        ActionItem cryItem          = new ActionItem(ID_CRY, "Cry", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.emo_cry));
        ActionItem arrousedItem     = new ActionItem(ID_ARROUSED, "Arroused", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.emo_arroused));
        ActionItem sleepyItem       = new ActionItem(ID_SLEEPY, "Sleepy", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.emo_sleepy));


        mQuickAction.addActionItem(happyItem);
        mQuickAction.addActionItem(sadtItem);
        mQuickAction.addActionItem(madItem);
        mQuickAction.addActionItem(cryItem);
        mQuickAction.addActionItem(arrousedItem);
        mQuickAction.addActionItem(sleepyItem);

        mMood = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnMood);
        mMood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mQuickAction.show(v);               
            }
        });

        //setup the action item click listener
        mQuickAction.setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(QuickAction quickAction, int pos, int actionId) {
                ActionItem actionItem = quickAction.getActionItem(pos);
                mood_selected = actionItem.getActionId();

                switch(mood_selected) {
                case 1:
                    mMood.setImageResource(R.drawable.emo_happy);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mMood.setImageResource(R.drawable.emo_sad);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mMood.setImageResource(R.drawable.emo_mad);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    mMood.setImageResource(R.drawable.emo_cry);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    mMood.setImageResource(R.drawable.emo_arroused);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    mMood.setImageResource(R.drawable.emo_sleepy);
                    break;

                }
            }
        });




        final QuickAction mQuickAction2     = new QuickAction(getActivity());

        ActionItem observation1         = new ActionItem(_ID1, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.observation_1));
        ActionItem observation2         = new ActionItem(_ID2, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.observation_2));
        ActionItem observation3         = new ActionItem(_ID3, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.observation_3));
        ActionItem observation4         = new ActionItem(_ID4, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.observation_4));
        ActionItem observation5         = new ActionItem(_ID5, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.observation_5));
        ActionItem observation6         = new ActionItem(_ID6, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.observation_6));
        ActionItem observation7         = new ActionItem(_ID7, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.observation_7));
        ActionItem observation8         = new ActionItem(_ID8, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.observation_8));
        ActionItem observation9         = new ActionItem(_ID9, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.observation_9));
        ActionItem observation10        = new ActionItem(_ID10, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.observation_10));
        ActionItem observation11        = new ActionItem(_ID11, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.observation_11));
        ActionItem observation12        = new ActionItem(_ID12, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.observation_12));
        ActionItem observation13        = new ActionItem(_ID13, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.observation_13));
        ActionItem observation14        = new ActionItem(_ID14, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.observation_14));
        ActionItem observation15        = new ActionItem(_ID15, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.observation_15));


        mQuickAction2.addActionItem(observation1);
        mQuickAction2.addActionItem(observation2);
        mQuickAction2.addActionItem(observation3);
        mQuickAction2.addActionItem(observation4);
        mQuickAction2.addActionItem(observation5);
        mQuickAction2.addActionItem(observation6);
        mQuickAction2.addActionItem(observation7);
        mQuickAction2.addActionItem(observation8);
        mQuickAction2.addActionItem(observation9);
        mQuickAction2.addActionItem(observation10);
        mQuickAction2.addActionItem(observation11);
        mQuickAction2.addActionItem(observation12);
        mQuickAction2.addActionItem(observation13);
        mQuickAction2.addActionItem(observation14);
        mQuickAction2.addActionItem(observation15);

        stamp = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnstamp);
        stamp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mQuickAction2.show(v);              
            }
        });

        //setup the action item click listener
        mQuickAction2.setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(QuickAction quickAction, int pos, int actionId) {
                ActionItem actionItem = quickAction.getActionItem(pos);
                stamp_selected = actionItem.getActionId();

                switch(stamp_selected) {
                case 1:
                    stamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.observation_1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    stamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.observation_2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    stamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.observation_3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    stamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.observation_4);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    stamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.observation_5);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    stamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.observation_6);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    stamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.observation_7);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    stamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.observation_8);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    stamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.observation_9);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    stamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.observation_10);
                    break;
                case 11:
                    stamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.observation_11);
                    break;
                case 12:
                    stamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.observation_12);
                    break;
                case 13:
                    stamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.observation_13);
                    break;
                case 14:
                    stamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.observation_14);
                    break;
                case 15:
                    stamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.observation_15);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });


        final QuickAction mQuickAction3     = new QuickAction(getActivity());

        ActionItem energy1      = new ActionItem(_ID1, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.energy_1));
        ActionItem energy2      = new ActionItem(_ID2, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.energy_2));
        ActionItem energy3      = new ActionItem(_ID3, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.energy_3));
        ActionItem energy4      = new ActionItem(_ID4, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.energy_4));
        ActionItem energy5      = new ActionItem(_ID5, "", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.energy_5));


        mQuickAction3.addActionItem(energy1);
        mQuickAction3.addActionItem(energy2);
        mQuickAction3.addActionItem(energy3);
        mQuickAction3.addActionItem(energy4);
        mQuickAction3.addActionItem(energy5);

        mEnergy = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnEnergy);
        mEnergy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mQuickAction3.show(v);              
            }
        });

        //setup the action item click listener
        mQuickAction3.setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(QuickAction quickAction, int pos, int actionId) {
                ActionItem actionItem = quickAction.getActionItem(pos);
                energy_selected = actionItem.getActionId();

                switch(energy_selected) {
                case 1:
                    mEnergy.setImageResource(R.drawable.energy_1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mEnergy.setImageResource(R.drawable.energy_2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mEnergy.setImageResource(R.drawable.energy_3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    mEnergy.setImageResource(R.drawable.energy_4);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    mEnergy.setImageResource(R.drawable.energy_5);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });



        mIntercorse = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnIntercorse);
        mPeriod = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPeriod);
        mHeadache = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnHeadache);
        mTest = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnTest);

        return view;
       }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clean your project. In Eclipse,

> Project -->Clean...   choose your project

Sometimes Eclipse doesn't pick up xml changes right away so it throws these class cast exceptions. Simply cleaning and rebuilding the project usually takes care of such errors. Its a quick and easy thing to do before pulling out all of your hair trying to figure out why you would get such an exception.

Also, I suggest using the xml tab when at all possible. IMHO, it is more flexible and easier to get the results you want. You can still have this issue when coding the xml manually but I think producing the layout you want is easier this way most of the time.

Comment: Thanks i appreciate the help and the suggestions! I try and get most of what i can in the graphical and they refine it in the xml... Just what i read as a productive way of accomplishing what you want. Anyways thanks again!

Comment: No problem, just giving you my 2 cents on the subject. Did cleaning fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout xml file is wrong.

not `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnEnergy"` but `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/btnEnergy"` not include "+"

@+id means add a new id, that would cause error.

Comment: Then why does it not do it now? or cause an error everytime?

`Must be a reference to another resource, in the form "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form "?[package:][type:]name".` See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: When you need to reference to another resource, "@+id" is not a good practice, because you have added the same ID to the ImageButton for twice. It will not cause an error everytime, but sometimes it cause crash like this.

Comment: Thanks for your input i'll take it under consideration.

Comment: Well this was somewhat the case back around Froyo and earlier. Today you can simply always add "+" and it will not cause any issue. They changed it to make it easier though I agree that it is somewhat better to distinct between "defining an id" and "referencing". Anyway there will not crash based on the usage of "+" (except you never ever used it for the id, but than the compiler should warn you before...)